# server reached pm.max_children setting when using Server side events

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, php-fpm

I'm using Oracle's Ampere 4 core 16GB server for hosting my php webapp. For server I choosed NGINX with PHP FPM there I uses a simple Server side event loop to establish a persistant connection to each client. But when there is few users logged in concurrently server becomes non responsive. FPM error log displays follwing,

> server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it
> NOTICE: Terminating ...
> NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!

My website generally needs to handle more than 200 concurrent connections. So I choosed SSE as it was mentioned to be more performant than short polling. 
**Can this issue be solved with increasing child count?**
**Is there a risk of exceeding server resources by doing so?**
**Should I stop using SSEs or whats your recommendation?**

Thank you very much! Silmplified version of my php script is below,

```
<?php
ob_implicit_flush(1);
ob_end_clean();
set_time_limit(0);

header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$var = $_GET["something"];


//SQL qry to write a value to database



    while (true) {
        if (connection_aborted() == 1) {
            break;
        }

        //another sql qry to check for changes in a value;
        //if value has changed echo 'something';

        sleep(100);
              
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
    exit();

?>
```

Comment: did you what the error told you? Considering using caching if acceptable

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I completely removed SSE script from my site cause I couldn't aford a full downtime again. Now I am afraid of reimplementing it cause I don't have any idea about what is the relationship between child count and simultanious connections or clients.